# Is there a way to read a pdf file's content in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-redux

I've been trying to see if I can read a pdf file's content from an input field in React and save the texts in a variable. I tried using pdfjs-dist package, it works in vanilla js and node js but for whatever reason, it doesn't work with react.

If you know any package that works kindly share

Comment: you need to provide your code and what issues you're encountering

Comment: @DerekPollard there's no code, i just need to know if there's a package or something that helps read a pdf file content in react. The ones i know of only work with js and node

Comment: Yes, it's the one you posted about. If it works in vanilla JS, it'll work in react with some massaging.

Comment: @DerekPollard It doesn't work with react. You can try it out and if it works share your code snippet as an answer and I'll happily check it

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you; I've used the library above with both react and vue on proprietary software so I know it works

Comment: @DerekPollard No i'm not saying you should write the code for me, just a snippet on what changes you made to the way it works in node to make it work with react

Comment: Please share the code you've written that doesn't work

Comment: @DerekPollard Nevermind, I've made it work... Thanks for making me try again, i'll post my code as the answer for anyone going through the same issue

Comment: Sounds good, glad you got it working!